# perl dbi submit checkbox values

Tags: forms, perl, checkbox, dbi

I have a form with checkboxes and I need to know what the best way to submit them to the database is. I have the following table setup:

```
roles    users    user_roles
-----    -----    ----------
id       id       user_id
                  role_id
```

I have a page where you can edit a user and assign them different roles via checkbox, then those checkboxes are saved in the user_roles table. Since editing a user's roles can involve either deleting rows or adding rows, this is how I currently handle it:

```
my $form_vals = (1=>1,2=>2); #submitted by user
my $db_vals = (3=>3); #gotten out of db
```

So I have these two hashes and I will compare the keys in `$form_vals` with the keys in `$db_vals`, then I see that I have two extra values that are not present in the database so I add them. And vice versa I find which values are no longer selected on the form by comparing the keys in `$db_vals` with the keys in `$form_vals` and then I delete those rows from the database. My question is, does anyone know of a better/easier way to do this? It's never really seemed obvious to me how to handle checkboxes and I'd like to know what best practice is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that this has much to do with check boxes per se.

Basically what you have is two array of arrays, [ (uid, rid), (uid, rid) ], and you want to make array1 (the one in your database) a copy of array2 (the user input from the checkboxes). You could have a multi select or a comma separated string, and the case would be the same. You have a user id, and you want that user to have only the roles supplied.

Two ways to achieve that would be to either

- Put both arrays in one hash each, do foreach key on the submitted, if not present in the database one do insert. Then do the same for the database hash and delete those not present in the submitted hash
- Delete everything from the member_role table and insert what's submitted.

You really have to know everything in the database and everything submitted and check twice if you don't want to delete everything and do a fresh insert. You can of course make a function doing this for you, hiding the ugliness a bit. Think about how you'd do if it was just two arrays and no database was around.